# Who are the earliest unlockable characters for each exploration power in Lego Batman 2: DC Super Heroes?

Tags: lego-batman-2-dc-super-heroes

Which characters are the earliest to unlock for each power needed for exploration in *Lego Batman 2: DC Super Heroes*?